# Disable Safari 5's “overscroll” behaviour using CSS or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, safari, webkit

Safari 5 on OS X Lion allows you to scroll past the visible bounds of the page, revealing a linen texture beneath it. It's a nice effect, but for some web apps – particularly those with fixed-position elements like a sidebar – it can be distracting. Does anyone know how to disable the effect using CSS or JavaScript? It must be possible, because some sites like Apple's own [iCloud](http://icloud.com) have done so.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a [blog post](http://www.smilingsouls.net/Blog/20110804114957.html) that talks about what you need to do to disable elastic scrolling on both Mac OS X and iOS devices.  According to the site it appears to be as simple as the following CSS rule for desktop browsers:

```
body { overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: Works like a charm; I figured it'd be something simple. Thanks, man.

Comment: Doesn't work for me - the page freezes and can't scroll to anywhere.

Comment: this doesn't work, just prevents all scrolling for me on safari

Comment: This is theoretically impossible to work, you would just prevent scrolling and that's all. I do not get it, why is this marked as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

```
body,
html {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Tested and verified with iOS8, and iOS9.

Comment: Doesn't work while using trackpad on safari

Answer (score -1):

```
html { overflow: hidden;}
body { overflow: scroll;}
```